# Faster function or script for computing a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, pandas-groupby

I have online user data with the following information,

```
df.head()

USER Timestamp  day_of_week Busi_days   Busi_hours
AAD 2017-07-11 09:31:44 TRUE    TRUE
AAD 2017-07-11 23:24:43 TRUE    FALSE
AAD 2017-07-12 13:24:43 TRUE    TRUE
SAP 2017-07-23 14:24:34 FALSE   FALSE
SAP 2017-07-24 16:58:49 TRUE    TRUE
YAS 2017-07-31 21:10:35 TRUE    FALSE
```

I wanted to compute the activity of USER column and create three new columns namely: 1. `Activity`: With the information based on how active the user is, meaning if the same user clicked more than twice then call it TRUE else false. 2.`Multiple_days:` If the user clicked the website on the more one day, if the same user clicked more than 2 days call the column TRUE else FALSE. 3. `Busniess_days:`  whether the user clicked on the weekdays, if the user clicked the website on businesses days within business hours then call it True else FALSE

I have the following script performing the above-mentioned task, but its really slow for my huge data frame `my data frame is 117Mb in size.` Any better solutions would be great

My try:

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
df['date'] = [x.date() for x in df.Timestamp]
target_df = pd.DataFrame()
target_df['USER'] = df.USER.unique()
a = df.groupby(['USER', 'date']).size()
a = a[a>1]
UID=pd.DataFrame(a).reset_index().USER.values

target_df['Active'] = [True if x in UID else False for x in target_df.USER.values]
a = df.groupby('USER')['Timestamp'].nunique()
a = a[a>1]
UUID2=pd.DataFrame(a).reset_index().USER.values 
target_df['Multiple_days'] = [True if x in UUID2 else False for x in target_df.USER.values]

a = df[(df.Busi_days==True)&(df.Busi_hours==True)].USER.unique()

target_df['Busi_weekday'] = [True if x in a else False for x in target_df.USER.values]

target_df.head()


USER Active  Multiple_days   Busi_weekday
AAD TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
SAP FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
YAS FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

Comment: What is `TA_log` ?

Comment: Sorry its df, typo I edited it TA_log is the name I used for my real data frame on the real script. Its df here on the question

Comment: Also in `a = df[(df.Busi_days==True)&(df.Busi_hours==True)].uuid.unique()` is typo.

Comment: yes, thanks for notifying that also. I just edited it in my question

Comment: @user1017373, can you indicate which bit is the bottleneck. There are a couple of ways you can find this: either printing timestamps as the script runs, or running through a profiler. Although we can make very good guesses, having this data will probably generate better answers.

Comment: All of these list comprehensions e.g [True if x in UID else False for x in ....] are for loops which should be vectorised to make the best use of pandas datastructure (built on numpy) for speedups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)

df['date'] = df.Timestamp.dt.floor('d')

u = df.USER.unique()
a = df.groupby(['USER', 'date']).size().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
a = a[a>1]
target_df = a[~a.index.duplicated()]
                .astype(bool).reindex(u, fill_value=False).to_frame(name='Active')

a = df.groupby('USER')['Timestamp'].nunique()
target_df['Multiple_days'] = a[a>1].astype(bool).reindex(u, fill_value=False)

a = df[(df.Busi_days==True)&(df.Busi_hours==True)].USER.unique()
target_df['Busi_weekday'] = target_df.index.isin(a)
print(target_df)

      Active  Multiple_days  Busi_weekday
USER                                     
AAD     True           True          True
SAP    False           True          True
YAS    False          False         False
```

EDIT:

Solution with custom function:

```
print (df1)
  USER   Timestamp day_of_week  Busi_days  Busi_hours
0  AAD  2017-07-11    09:31:44       True        True
1  AAD  2017-07-11    23:24:43       True       False
2  AAD  2017-07-12    13:24:43       True        True
3  SAP  2017-07-23    14:24:34      False       False
4  SAP  2017-07-24    16:58:49       True        True
5  YAS  2017-07-31    21:10:35       True       False

def func(df, time_col, user_col):
    df[time_col] = pd.to_datetime(df[time_col])

    df['date'] = df[time_col].dt.floor('d')

    u = df.USER.unique()
    a = df.groupby([user_col, 'date']).size().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    a = a[a>1]
    target_df = (a[~a.index.duplicated()]
                    .astype(bool).reindex(u, fill_value=False).to_frame(name='Active'))

    a = df.groupby(user_col)[time_col].nunique()
    target_df['Multiple_days'] = a[a>1].astype(bool).reindex(u, fill_value=False)

    a = df.loc[(df.Busi_days==True)&(df.Busi_hours==True), user_col].unique()
    target_df['Busi_weekday'] = target_df.index.isin(a)
    return target_df

#inputs are name of DataFrame, column for timestamp and column for user    
print (func(df1, 'Timestamp', 'USER'))
      Active  Multiple_days  Busi_weekday
USER                                     
AAD     True           True          True
SAP    False           True          True
YAS    False          False         False
```

Comment: Thanks , but it throws error as, ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: Is it possible to make it as a function which can be used elsewhere?

Comment: Sure, what are inputs of function?

Comment: The data frame as mentioned above, or I wanted to it be command-line executable.

Comment: Yes, we dont understand. What are inputs in function? Columns name `timestamp` only?

Comment: Yes, USERID and Time stamp